# Does permutation symmetry follow the Wigner's theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, fermions, bosons, identical-particles

The permutation symmetry for boson/ferminon is
$$
P_{12} | 12  \rangle = \pm |21\rangle 
$$

I may think it as a linear unitary transformation, since 
$$
P_{12}^{\dagger} P_{12} =P_{12} P_{12} =1
$$
Is this an example of the [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem), since Wigner's theorem seems to encode all symmetries in quantum mechanics?

My question comes from, the derivation of Wigner's theorem is based on the result of measurement before/after symmetry transformation should be the same. 
$$
| ( \Phi, \Psi )|^2 = | ( U\Phi, U\Psi )|^2
$$

But, permutation "symmetry" leads to observable consequences, e.g., exchange force, Bose-Einstein condensation.  It looks like this "symmetry" is not the same as before/after transformation.